# How do you refer to github actions variables in an azure pipeline yaml file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-actions, azure-pipelines-yaml

If i want to pass the below variables from github actions to an azure piplelines yaml file how do i refer to them and use them  in the azure yaml pipeline?

```
    - uses: Azure/pipelines@v1
  with:
    azure-devops-project-url: 'https://dev.azure.com/organization/project-name'
    azure-pipeline-name: 'pipeline-name' # name of the Azure pipeline to be triggered
    azure-devops-token: '${{ secrets.azureconnection }}'
    azure-pipeline-variables:  '{"variable1": "value1", "variable2": "value2"}' # optional stringified json
```

Answer (score -1):

The GitHub page for the project has an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/pipelines/issues/40) that indicates that v1 was not properly passing variables to Azure Pipelines. v1.2 corrects the issue.

Comment: i tried that but it doesnt work , the jobs runs but there the variable value is blank

Comment: @itye1970 What does your Azure Pipelines YAML look like?

Comment: - uses: Azure/pipelines@v1.2
        with:
          azure-devops-project-url: 'https://dev.azure.com/project'
          azure-pipeline-name: 'test' # name of the Azure pipeline to be triggered
          azure-devops-token: '${{ secrets.adotoken }}'
          #azure-pipeline-variables:  '{"pr_number": "github.event.pull_request.number"}'
          azure-pipeline-variables:  '{"pr_number": "TEST"}' # optional stringified json

Comment: in the azure-pipelines when trying to echo the variable it is blank

Comment: steps:
    - script: echo $(githubvar)
    - script: echo ${{variables['githubvar']}}
    #- script: echo ${{variables['githubvar']}